# embed .obj (or any 3d file) on a website

Tags: flash, web, 3d, embed

How would I go about embedding a 3d object onto my website  that allows drag to rotate (preferably all directions not just horizontally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript, it should be possible with one of the javascript 3D engines:

[free javascript 3D engine](http://www.google.com/search?q=free%20javascript%203d%20engine)

I have no experience with javascript 3D so I can't comment much except note the probable possibility.

Flash: several 3D graphics engines:

[free flash 3D engines](http://www.google.com/search?q=free%20flash%203D%20engine)

I am working with Away3D and I find it fit for my needs. It has an AIR app called Prefab made by one of the developers that makes work with 3d formats easier. Whether other engines have the same or harder workflow I can not comment.

Which one you choose is up to you though. Be prepared to battle it out for a few days to get it working though, it can be hard if you are new to this stuff.

There are other options, Java applet or Unity3D plugin, but they probably are not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript WebGL engines like Tree.js or Frak. There are also some ready services like [3D Wayfinder](http://www.3dwayfinder.com), where you can upload your model and embed it in your website.