# How to render a 3D model made in 3ds Max on a web page?

Tags: html, 3d, 3dsmax, 3d-rendering

I have .obj, .3ds and .ase files from a client, who has created this 3D model using 3ds Max. I need to display this 3D model on a web page. I can use HTML5 as well.

How to do it with or without HTML5?

Comment: seems like a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768447/embed-obj-or-any-3d-file-on-a-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using something like Unity web player, you would have to create a bit of a framework to support exactly what you want but this shouldnt be too difficult, you could then run this on any browser with the unity web player plugin.

There are also other players which might be of use, although not necesserily all web versions.  Inventor handles 3ds max files just fine and has possibility of other players, I'm not sure if there is a web version though, might be worth looking into.

There are a few projects out there that could deffinately help such as Three.js, this would deffinately be a place to start.

Comment: @John Taylor I can not use Unity web player, because I want an implement such in which user does not require a plugin.

I also found that three.js can be helpful but din't find a simple solution in that too to render an already created 3d model.

Comment: Id suggest looking more into Three.js or a flash based approach (although as you said no plugins, flash is out of the question).  Three.js provides everything you need to render to the web, you will however need to create the converter to convert from a 3ds max file or an obj file to whatever three.js needs.